# Match each row in a table to a row in another table based on the difference between row timestamps

Tags: r

I have two unevenly-spaced time series that each measure separate attributes of the same system. The two series's data points are not sampled at the same times, and the series are not the same length. I would like to match each row from series A to the row of B that is closest to it in time. What I have in mind is to add a column to A that contains indexes to the closest row in B. Both series have a time column measured in Unix time (eg. 1459719755).

for example, given two datasets

```
a  time
2  1459719755
4  1459719772
3  1459719773

b  time
45 1459719756
2  1459719763
13 1459719766
22 1459719774
```

The first dataset should be updated to

```
a  time        index
2  1459719755  1
4  1459719772  4
3  1459719773  4
```

since `B[1,]$time` has the closest value to `A[1,]$time`, `B[4,]$time` has the closest value to `A[2,]$time` and `A[3,]$time`.

Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: If the tables are sorted by time then you can do a merge-style single pass through both tables. What do you want to do with the joined data? Get a single table with both / more columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(1+ecdf(bdat$time)(adat$time)*nrow(bdat))
[1] 1 4 4
```

Why should this work? The ecdf function returns another function that has a value from 0 to 1. It returns the "position" in the "probability range" [0,1] of a new value in a distribution of values defined by the first argument to `ecdf`. The expression is really just rescaling that function's result to the range [1, nrow(bdat)]. (I think it's flipping elegant.)

Another approach would be to use `approxfun` on the sorted values of `bdat$time` which would then let get you interpolated values. These might need to be rounded. Using them as indices would instead truncate to integer.

```
apf <- approxfun( x=sort(bdat$time), y=seq(length( bdat$time))  ,rule=2)
apf( adat$time)
#[1] 1.000 3.750 3.875
round( apf( adat$time))
#[1] 1 4 4
```

In both case you are predicting a sorted value from its "order statistic". In the second case you should check that ties are handled in the manner you desire.

Comment: I don't recognize this syntax: `func(x)(y)`.

Comment: That's because you don't often use `ecdf`. A function returning a function is not that common, but when it occurs you can simply use it in place by passing arguments in parentheses. Try typing `ecdf(bdat$time)` where bdat is the second dataframe name. No different than `(function(x){mean(x)})( rnorm(10) )`. Returned  0.1410476 when I just tried it.

Comment: I agree, this is flipping elegant! Though I believe the more generally applicable solution will require the second approach you mention, since `ecdf()()` always rounds inputs down to the closest lower sample point. Could you show how to use `approxfun`?

Comment: This is just perfect. Thanks!